# Filter df so values are equal across groups - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas `df` that contains values at various time points. I perform a groupby of these time points and values. I'm hoping the filter the output so both groups contain values at each time point. If either group does not contain a value at that time point I want to drop that row.

Using the `df` below, there is values for `Group A` and `Group B` at various time points. However, time point `3,4,6` only contain one item from either `Group A` or `Group B`. When there isn't at least two items per group, I want to drop these rows altogether.

The ordering matters and not the total amount. So if there are missing items for either `Group` at a specific time point, I want to drop these rows.

Note: the df only contains a max of one value per group at each time point. But my actual data could contain numerous. The main concern is dropping rows where at least one group is absent.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6],   
        'Group' : ['A','B','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','B'],                    
        'Val_A' : [6,7,4,5,4,4,9,6,7,8],  
        'Val_B' : [1,2,2,3,2,1,2,1,4,9],         
        'Val_C' : [1,2,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,7],                      
    }) 


Group_A = df1.loc[df1['Group'] == 'A']
Group_B = df1.loc[df1['Group'] == 'B']

Group_A = list(Group_A.groupby(['Time'])['Val_A'].apply(list))
Group_B = list(Group_B.groupby(['Time'])['Val_B'].apply(list))

print(df1)
print(Group_A)
print(Group_B) 

   Time Group  Val_A  Val_B  Val_C
0     1     A      6      1      1
1     1     B      7      2      2
2     1     B      4      2      2
3     2     A      5      3      3
4     2     B      4      2      4
5     3     A      4      1      5
6     4     B      9      2      7
7     5     A      6      1      8
8     5     B      7      4      9
9     6     B      8      9      7
[[6], [5], [4], [6]]
[[2, 2], [2], [2], [4], [9]]
```

I can't use `dropna` or `drop_duplicates`. Furthermore, data may contain items for `Group B` and not `Group A`. So I'm hoping to find a function that can handle both instances.

Intended Output:

```
  Time Group  Val_A  Val_B  Val_C
0     1     A      6      1      1
1     1     B      7      2      2
2     1     B      4      2      2
3     2     A      5      3      3
4     2     B      4      2      4
7     5     A      6      1      8
8     5     B      7      4      9
[[6], [5], [6]]
[[2, 2], [2], [4]]
```

Comment: Is it the number of rows you want to make uniform or is it the sum of the values? Why is 'Time=3' removed in the example output?

Comment: Number of rows. There is no value for `Group B` at the 3rd time point. Hence I want to drop that row so the output is even for each `Group`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Time' as a grouping of each and 'set()' to do a single comparison. The comparison results are extracted conditionally. Does this fit your intent?

```
mask = list(set(Group_A['Time'])^set(Group_B['Time']))
df1[~(df1['Time'].isin(mask))]
    Time    Group   Val_A   Val_B   Val_C
0   1   A   6   1   1
1   1   B   7   2   2
2   1   B   4   2   2
3   2   A   5   3   3
4   2   B   4   2   4
7   5   A   6   1   8
8   5   B   7   4   9
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about which row you drop, you could pick the first n rows in each group where n is the smallest number of rows in any group:

```
df1.groupby('Group').head(df1.groupby('Group')['Val_A'].count().min())
```

Or, if you only want rows with a value of 'Time' in each group, you could do the following:

```
df1.groupby('Time').filter(lambda x: len(x['Val_A']) > 1)
```

Or, if you want to check that you have each group (e.g. A and B) at each point in time and they only appear once at that point

```
df1.groupby('Time').filter(lambda x: {'A','B'} == set(x['Group']) and len(x) == 2)
```

Comment: The second option works. I want to keep it even for each row `(Time)`. However, I don't want to hard code the Values. My dataset could contain more values for `Group B` compared to `Group A`. I'm hoping to find a method that can handle both instances.

Comment: And you are always looking for both groups (A and B) for each Time? The column you check doesn't matter:

E.g.

df1.groupby('Time').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

Or, if you want to explicitly check that you have A and B for each time

df1.groupby('Time').filter(lambda x: {'A','B'} == set(x['Group']))

Or, if you want to check that you have A and B and only one value of each

df1.groupby('Time').filter(lambda x: {'A','B'} == set(x['Group']) and len(x) == 2)

Comment: Yep, was just altering the question. You've got it. Apologies once again, my dataset could contain more than 2 values per group. I only want to drop if there is no values for a group. there could be 10 for Group A and 1 for Group B and I'd want to keep it. I only want to drop if there's none.

Comment: Then this is the one you want, right? df1.groupby('Time').filter(lambda x: {'A','B'} == set(x['Group']))